# When debugging is started ,then put break down point on the variable this variable always show value as 1

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int mark , total ,count ;
    count = 2 ;
    total = 0 ;
    while (count <= 10)
    {
        printf("Enter mark : ");
        scanf("%d",&mark);
        total = total  + mark ;
        ++ count ;
    }
    printf("Total : %.2f\n",total/10.0);
    return 0 ;
}
```

if we set breakdown step as count=2 when debugging start why show count as 1

Comment: If you put a break point on that line and it stops there it means the line has not executed yet. Before a local variable is set it has an indeterminate value so can be anything. Step the debugger to execute the line.

Comment: Insert breakpoint at next line and type the gdb's command si and recheck the value of count variable.

Answer (score 1):

When the breakdown line is `count=2`, it will break at this point. Therefore, it still is not executed. As a result, the value can be change and different.